# Find processes or applications that are using microphone in windows C#

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0

I want to check if any program is accessing the microphone. Based on the access I can show user notification or turn on light indicator etc.

So far I saw unanswered similar questions or only the solution of image processing and checking if the microphone icon is on taskbar. But that is not the right solution. So on windows 11, is there any way to find microphone access?